# Spring Boot REST - Required String parameter is not present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot

I have trouble with sending data to Spring Boot server. I check with Postman, everything is good, but I use axios library of ReactJS, i get error

```
Required String parameter 'name' is not present.
```

## addProduct funtion

```
addProduct = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
    var { productName, productPrice, productStatus } = this.state;
    callApi('product/add', 'POST', {
        name: productName,
        price: productPrice,
        status: productStatus
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

## productController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/product")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRespository productRespository;

    @GetMapping(path = "/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<Product> getAllProduct(){
        return productRespository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/add")
    @ResponseBody
    public String createProduct(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam Integer price, @RequestParam String status){
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(name);
        product.setPrice(price);
        product.setStatus(status);
        productRespository.save(product);
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

## apiCaller.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Config from './../constants/Config';

export default function callApi(endpoint, method, body) {
    return axios({
        method: method,
        url: `http://localhost:8000/api/${endpoint}`,
        data: body,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

how can I solve?

Comment: Append name in requested URL like `'product/add?name='+productName`

Comment: how does your RESTController method look like?

Comment: Where do you get that error? How is defined your request on server side? It may be good to show also `callApi`

Comment: I get that error from server. I user axios to send request to server.

Comment: Does changing `@RequestParam` to `@RequestBody` in all `createProduct` params solve your issue?

Comment: @barbsan I tried but I still got that above error

Comment: Can you show that axios call in `callApi`? Have you inspected your request in your browser's console?

Comment: I have checked and got error "the server responded with a status of 400"

Comment: By "inspect" I meant to compare url, parameters and headers with the ones you send using postman

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your rest service expects name, price, status as request parameters and in spring these are mandatory by default.
But in your react code you are not sending these as request parameters, instead you are sending them as request body.

As name is the first param as soon as it's not available spring throws 'name' not available exception, but once you fix it it will throw for price and then status. So fix them all together.

You have to either change your controller method like below, which will be more code efficient and rest standard way.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/add")
@ResponseBody
public String createProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
    productRespository.save(product);
    return "OK";
}
```

OR
change your react code to send them in the request like below. But for 'POST' methods this is not recommended. Because this will reveal the information passed in url itself.

```
addProduct = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var { productName, productPrice, productStatus } = this.state;
    callApi('product/add?name=' + productName +  '&price=' + productPrice + '&status=' + productStatus , 'POST', {}).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you should never really be using the POST method with request params. Doing this, you can just paste this into your browser `http://localhost:8080/product/add?name=myname&price=100&status=ok` and this will successfully call the api and bypass any business logic implemented on your react client. You don't want to give access to insert data in your database this way

Comment: I have a question want to ask you. The paramaters in url to server will correspond to the field in a table on server side, right? For example http://localhost:8080/product/add?name=myname&price=100&status=ok
name, price, status will correspond name, price, status fields in product table

Comment: Not necessarily. By default it uses the same variable name to map to Java variables on the server side. But you can change the `@RequestParam` or `@RequestBody` to map the json variable to a differently named Java variable. As it is currently coded on your application. They should map directly by default. Similar convention follows when mapping your Java variable to a a Database Entity when you use the `@Table` and `@Column` annotations

Comment: It doesn't. Actually spring takes the parameter names in the controller method you have put the name, price, status.

But you have option to pass the different request param name like below
@RequestParam(name = "differentName") String anotherName

in this case you have to send request 
localhost:8080/product/add?differentName=TestingName

and in your code product.setName(anotherName);

So here you can see your request param and method param name and product field name all are different. And as @NabeelMehmood suggested using request param is not recommendable for creations.

Answer (score 2):

The `@RequestParam` annotation gets its data from the url. Which should be like:

`?name=myname&price=100&status=ok`

The `@RequestBody` annotation is what you are looking for if you are sending the data as a json object in the body of the request. Make sure you also set the `Content-Type` in your `axios` request to `application/json`

```
axios.post('url', JSON.stringify({
        "name": productName,
        "price": productPrice,
        "status": productStatus,
     }) , { headers: {  "Content-Type": "application/json"  }
})
```

Comment: thank you, I have changed header but server return error 'Required String parameter 'name' is not present'

Comment: Okay. Try running `JSON.stringify(data)` on your data object that contains `name` `price` and `status`. Also make sure you set the key values of the object in double quotes. Like `"name" : productName` `"price": 200` and so on.
Ill update my answer. If it still doesn't work. Please log the request object you receive in Java system console and add the output to your question

Answer (score 0):

you either need to change the parameters of your add method to a single `@RequestBody Product` parameter. Or you should include all the parameters as query parameter in your Axios request ex: `product/add?name=myname&price=100&status=ok`

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong HTTP method. expected was POST and I was trying GET method